# My application successfully deployed in Azure but I can't hit the URL

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure, deployment

Deployment succesful in Azure but when I click on my URL I get an a 503 error?

[image]

This is a Linux OS Web app (App is Node/React) I think it might have something to do with the low CPU resources as I am on the free plan in Azure?

Comment: if you can post the error that would be useful

Comment: I get this error in the console ---> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Temporarily Unavailable). In kuku docker log --> ERROR - Container <myApp> didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080, failing site start

Comment: You can host the App using free tier.Post your application configs.

Comment: I am using free tier (F1)

Answer (score 0):

When you browse to the app, it returns a HTTP "502 Bad Gateway" error or a HTTP "503 Service Unavailable" error.

This problem is often caused by application level issues, such as:

- requests taking a long time
- application using high memory/CPU
- application crashing due to an exception.

Troubleshooting steps to solve "502 bad gateway" and "503 service unavailable" errors

Troubleshooting can be divided into three distinct tasks, in sequential order:

- [Observe and monitor application behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-http-502-http-503#observe)
- [Collect data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-http-502-http-503#collect)
- [Mitigate the issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-http-502-http-503#mitigate)

I would suggest you to go through these troubleshooting steps, it will help finding the right error.